# Using 'AS' command, I get the following error - why?

Tags: sql

When I run this, it works.

```
   select avg(SQLProcessCPU)
    from   dbo.TrackCPU
    where  CaptureTime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE())
```

But, when I run it with an: 'as' command.  it throws an error.  Does anyone know why?  Please help.

```
select avg(SQLProcessCPU)
    from   dbo.TrackCPU
    where  CaptureTime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE()) as CPU
```

Error Message:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

Comment: As stands for Alias. But alias of what in your case?

Comment: You can use AS after an expression in the select-list, or after a table expression in the FROM clause.  You can't use AS in the WHERE clause -- unless it is inside a sub-select statement in the WHERE clause, of course.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Looks like it might be SQL Server, but it is always as well to say.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server is the database that I am using.  I do not need an explaination of what this is doing, but help in figuring out how to fix the syntax error.  Can someone help with the syntax error?

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
select avg(SQLProcessCPU)  as CPU
    from   dbo.TrackCPU
    where  CaptureTime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

The (optional) AS keyword is used to assign an *alias* (ie a temporary "name" for the life of the query) to a selected column or table.

Try this:

```
select avg(SQLProcessCPU) AS CPU
...
```

Or, because it's optional, just

```
select avg(SQLProcessCPU) CPU
...
```

Comment: It is a syntax problem.  That I need a solution to for.  For example this query works and returns values, but, when I try to run an individual portion of it as I shared in the beginning of this post, it does not work.

Comment: Example:

    select getdate() as PullTime,
   (select Min(SQLAgentStatus)
    from   dbo.TrackSQLAgentStatus) as SQLAgentStatus , 
    (select Max(MemoryGrants)
    from   dbo.TrackMemoryGrants) as MemoryGrants,
   (SELECT AVG(PageLifeExpectancy)
 FROM TrackPLE )  as PLE,
   (select avg(FreePages)
    from   dbo.TrackFreePages ) as FreePages,  
   (select avg(SQLProcessCPU)
    from   dbo.TrackCPU
    where  CaptureTime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE())) as CPU

Answer (score 0):

'AS' command can be used only in **select** condition or while considering a query as table,
'AS' command cannot be used in **where** condition

Answer (score 0):

As is used as an alias to the column we are retrieving, so use as after your column name which you want to retrieve